# Refresh data and reset countdown timer after interval of time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

**Index.php**

This is my main file where the countdown is happening. It's a simple countdown script. The next file "**Select.php**" contains the code that needs to get run after the countdown is done, and also I need the countdown to refresh to current time +1 hour. The best thing is if this is possible to do with ajax, but if not then it would work that the page refreshes for each hour.

A problem I faced when I tried to implement this codes with each other is that for each time I refresh the page, a new row from the database was selected. What I need is that for only when the countdown is done, a new row from the database is selected.

*I have tried using cron jobs, but I did not manage to get it working.*  **:(**

```
  <script>
  var CountDownTimer;

CountDownTimer = function(dt, id) {
  var _day, _hour, _minute, _second, end, selector, showRemaining, timer;
  selector = document.getElementById(id);
  end = new Date(dt);
  _second = 1000;
  _minute = _second * 60;
  _hour = _minute * 60;
  _day = _hour * 24;
  showRemaining = function() {
    var days, distance, hours, minutes, now, seconds;
    now = new Date();
    distance = end - now;
    if (distance <= 0) {
        CountDownTimer("<?php echo $expire_date; ?> <?php echo $expire_time; ?>:00", "countdown");
        return;
    }
    days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
    return selector.innerHTML =  minutes + " mins " + seconds + " secs";
  };
  return timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
};

CountDownTimer("<?php echo $expire_date; ?> <?php echo $expire_time; ?>:00", "countdown");

  </script>
```

**Select.php**

Here is the code that needs to run after the countdown in the main file is done.

```
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["username"];
    }
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I can see here is that if the page reloads then the timer will reset.

If you need the script to run every hour then you really should look at getting it running using cron.

`0 * * * * /path/to/php /full/path/to/your/php/file.php`